# Custom Page Template for "Older Posts" Pages

Tags: pagination, templates, page-template

My home page feed has a variety of items including a featured post and other features that I'd only like present on the home feed. When a user clicks on pagination to load older posts, I'd like to load up a new page template without all the home page bells and whistles. Is there a WP template file I'm overlooking or is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `is_home()` conditional tag to check whether or not the home page is being displayed or not.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
    // Do your fancy loop here with extra bells and whistles
} else {
    // This is not a homepage (i.e. paginated page)
    // Do a stripped down version of your loop above with no bells and whistles
}
?>
```

Reference to [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) on the WordPress Codex

Comment: Awesome. Combo'd this with the is_paged function and worked perfectly. If on the home page and NOT paged (!is_paged()) then load up all home page elements.